# Knowing TYPE parameters accepted values for RQGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, rqgis

I'm trying to use RQGIS interface with QGIS to create a polygon grid. One of the required parameters is TYPE.

Where can i know the type of parameters to this algorithm? and to others?

From

[data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8dmwpzdfD55bkpRVVhCU21oNGc)

Code:

```
neto  <- readRDS("/path/") #download data from link

# Finding QGIS algoritms 
dir_tmp <- "/my/path/"
my_env <- set_env()
find_algorithms(search_term = "grid")
params <- get_args_man(alg = "qgis:creategrid", qgis_env = my_env)

params$TYPE <- "polygon"
params$EXTENT <- nnetpro
params$HSPACING <- "10" does it accept numeric?
params$VSPACING <- "10" does it accept numeric?
params$CRS <- "EPSG:31983" #does it work with CRS("+init=epsg:31983")?
params$OUTPUT <- file.path(dir_tmp, "g10m.shp")


out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:creategrid",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = my_env)

Error in run_qgis(alg = "qgis:creategrid", params = params, load_output = params$OUTPUT,  : 
Error: Wrong parameter value: polygon
```

Comment: According to the docs https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/creategrid.html the values are 0:Rectangle Line, 1:Rectangle Polygon, 2:Diamond Polygon and 3:Hexagon Polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you want to use another projection, therefore we reproject your data:

```
library("sp")
neto  <- readRDS("neto.rds")
neto_projected <- spTransform(neto,  CRS("+init=epsg:31983"))
```

Next, we access the function arguments of "qgis:creategrid".

```
library("RQGIS")
qgis_env <- set_env(root = "C:/OSGeo4W64/")
params <- get_args_man(alg = "qgis:creategrid", qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

To access the options for a specific QGIS geoalgorithm, use `get_options`:

```
get_options(alg = "qgis:creategrid", qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

You can also access its online help:

```
open_help(alg = "qgis:creategrid", qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

Though I have to admit that the online help in this case is a bit confusing...

Let's specify the arguments accordingly:

```
params$TYPE <- 1
# extent has to be given in the form of: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
params$EXTENT <-  paste(as.vector(raster::extent(neto_projected)), 
                        collapse = ", ")
```

Obviously, you would like to use a 10 m spacing. That's why we have reprojected your data in the first place. However, be careful if you use another projection, e.g., when using WGS84 10 would correspond to 10 decimal degrees.

```
params$HSPACING <- 10
params$VSPACING <- 10
params$CRS <- "EPSG:31983" 
params$OUTPUT <- file.path(tempdir(), "g10m.shp")
```

Now run QGIS. Due to your fine resolution, this takes a little while.

```
out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:creategrid",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

Comment: I forgot to say that everything was in EPSG:31983, in that case, is it  necessary to write the CRS? anyways, the get_options and open_help are the key. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your neto-shapefile used the WGS84 projection. Anyways, you need to specify the CRS-argument. Not doing so would result in an QGIS error message saying "Wrong parameter value: None".